# Why are JFrame, JDialog, JApplet (from JRootPane) heavyweight

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I know why these components are called heavyweight components. What I'm really interested in is why they were not implemented as lightweight. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396878/in-java-jframe-is-heavy-weight-component-or-light-weight-component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These components are windows of different kind. If you want to create a window in the operationg system you need to call some OS native code, because there is no way to do it in Java. More than that, all the user input events (mouse, keyboard, etc) are dispatched by the OS to the appropriate OS window. Java components listen to these events in the native code and  send them to the java level via JNI. To sum up: it is just impossible to do them lightweight.