# How JFrame is light weight?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

JFrame is Extending Frame. Then, How JFrame is lightweight but Frame is heavyweight?

I red this [article](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs3283/ftp/Java/swingConnect/special_report/painting/painting.html) but still i didn't get how JFrame achieves its lightweight property?

I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396878/in-java-jframe-is-heavy-weight-component-or-light-weight-component) that JFrame is heavyweight but other Components starts with J* are lightweight. How other Swing components achieves this. I need bit of technical details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it's not. Both are heavy weight components, but because `JFrame` has been setup to support the `JRootPane`, which contains the content pane (and possibly) the glass pane (as well as the `JMenuBar`), it is consider "light weight", because it's been deliberately configured to support light weight components

Essentially `JFrame` and `JWindow` have been modified as light weight containers that support light weight components

Answer (score 2):

it is still a heavyweight component because it(JFrame) inherits from the Frame.And it is not belong to the JComponents which is lightweight components.

Heavyweight means each Java component has a native peer associated with it. A native peer is an OS-specific component... AWT is heavyweight, so if you create a AWT Button, on the Windows platform an MFC button is created, on *nix a Motif button is created, etc.

Lightweight means that there is not a native peer associated with the java component. This is done by having only the top-level component be heavyweight and all the lightweight components are drawn on to it. Swing is lightweight.

Of course, AWT and Swing are specific to standard Java (J2SE). Under J2ME it depends on what sort of device you are using. If you are using a more powerful device, like the Sharp Zaurus, then you have AWT and functionality pretty close to J2SE levels. If you have something like a Java-Enabled cell phone, you don't have all the capabilites that you need for a fully featured GUI, so there are special libraries used for making these applications. You'd need to look at the APIs provided by the device manufacturer most probably.

Answer (score 1):

`JFrames` are `heavyweight`, since it's impossible to create a task-view-level window in most OS without creating a "heavy" `AWT` window. `Lightweight` components can replace internal widgets with java-based stuff that doesn't require `JNI` calls, but windows are the special case. `JFrame` does let you do custom renders, though. Also, if you're using other lightweight stuff, then I suggest using `JFrame` as well since it makes the rendering more efficient overall than mixing light and heavy components.

It is still a heavyweight component because it`(JFrame)` inherits from the `Frame`. And it is not belong to the `JComponents` which is `lightweight components`.